# MFC crashing at runtime when reaching code line SetDlgItemText( , )

Tags: mfc

Debug output says:

```
First-chance exception at 0x00007FF96B451DB3 (ntdll.dll) in myapp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000053B3330FC8.
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF96B451DB3 (ntdll.dll) in myapp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000053B3330FC8.
```

This issue is occurring at Server computer,while at local computer its running fine. Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this:

```
if(NULL != GetSafeHwnd())
    SetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT, _T("Tra la la"));
```

or

```
if(NULL != GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT)->GetsafeHwnd())
    GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT)->SetWindowText(_T("Tra la la"));
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, but its still failing. previously it was giving ntdll.dll error now it's giving gdi32.dll error. Please help!

Comment: Thank you. The second option is also not working, Please help!

Comment: Then you have to create some traces on your code ... for instance, before SetDlgItemText check the state of your control .. use MessageBoxes, or traces, etc. ... or even better, check the content of the stack, as xMRI said.

Comment: After crashing, the call stack just has : > gdi32.dll!AllocateAnalysis() Unknown

Comment: It goes into an infinite loop, when it comes to SetWindowText(..)

Comment: Then the problem is inside of your code, the code that call "SetWindowText" ... I guess

Comment: But the same code is running fine on my local computer.

Comment: Agree, but the condition are not the same. :) That is why are you front with this situation.

Comment: I have two SetDlgItemText() for same ID, but that is not an issue right?
I have temporarily removed the second SetDlgItemText() function, it's working fine now.

Comment: SetDlgItemText pointed to the same ID could be a problem ... just give one of him another ID :)

Comment: Okay, Thank you everyone!